# como reinstalar Realmswitf en Xcode9?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

me pasaron un proyecto antiguo que esta en switf version 2.* , acabo de instalar el Xcode9 pero me salió un aviso que me dijo que solo soporta versiones de 3.* y que lo abra con Xcode 8 pero no encuentro el Xcode 8 solo el Xcode 9, y cuando abrí el proyecto y lo ejecute me sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esa libreria ya vino instalada con el proyecto

espero su ayuda gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para esto debes ir a las configuraciones de tu Xcode (command + ,) ir a la pestaña de location y en la opción command line tools cámbiala por el Xcode que estas usando actualmente, esto usualmente sucede cuando usas Carthage (si es así ejecuta en la consola el comando ``Carthage update`)